# Trying to understand the motivation of the curvature tensor in Lee's book about Riemannian manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am trying to understand the following passage from Lee's book on Riemannian manifolds. Unfortunately there are a few things I am not sure about.[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why do we have $\nabla_{\partial_{1}}Z=0$, if $x^{2}=0$. I tried to use
   [image]

as well as

[image]

2. Why is the following statement true?
   [image]
   My guess is because of ODEs.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $Z$ is constructed by first parallel transporting $z \in T_pM$ first along the $x^1$-axis, i.e., along the coordinate curve $t \mapsto (t, 0)$. The tangent vector to this curve is $\partial_1$, so this just means that $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z = 0$ when $x^2 = 0$.
2. This is by uniqueness of parallel transport, which is (as you suggest) a consequence of the uniqueness of solutions to linear ODEs. See Theorem 4.31 and Theorem 4.32 in the same book.

Comment: There's a small technical point in (1) worth mentioning. In order to conclude that $\nabla_{\partial_1}Z = 0$ when $x^2 = 0$ from the fact that $D_tZ \equiv 0$ (where the covariant derivative is taken along the $x^1$-axis curve), we need to know that $Z$ is extendible, i.e., actually defined in a neighborhood of the $x^1$-axis. For then we may appeal to Theorem 4.24(iii), which implies that, when $x^2 = 0$, $$\nabla_{\partial_1}Z = D_tZ = 0.$$ This extendibility holds because we've defined $Z$ on the entire coordinate chart by parallel transporting it along the other coordinate curves.